# Replace all occurrences of PHP function name with SED

Tags: php, regex, sed, find

I have a PHP file with multiple calls of function `my_function()` and I want to replace it with `blah_blah()`, just rename the function name everywhere. I have also `another_my_function()` there which I don't wan't to be replaced.

Here I've created the regular expression:

```
[^\w\*]my_function\(
```

Which means that the prefix should be some special character, than function name with starting round bracket. I replace it in a folder so here we go:

```
find my_folder_name -type f -exec sed -i 's/[^\w\*]my_function(/blah_blah(/g' {} \;
```

Round bracket is not a special character for sed so we don't need to escape it.
The problem is, I'm sure you noticed, that it will replace the function names including the prefix symbol `[^\w\*]`.

How can I replace only the name of function?

Comment: `\b` instead, for word boundary?

Comment: And what is the full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is correct solution, thanks to Marc B!

```
find my_folder_name -type f -exec sed -i 's/\bmy_function(/blah_blah(/g' {} \;
```